# Handling Oracle errors in bash

Tags: bash, oracle11g

I have some bash scripts which do some `DML` in Oracle. I would like to catch Oracle errors in a log file (only the `ORA-XXXXX` part), but in addition to Oracle error messages, in output I get directory content from which the bash script is being executed (almost like `ls` command was executed). Is there a clean way to get the only Oracle error code and silence/redirect the directory contents?

```
#!/bin/bash

. /path/to/configfile/config.conf

res=`sqlplus -S $my_user << !
    set head off;
    set feedback off;

    select * from give_me_error;

!`
```

Output from the code above is as follows:

select other_script.sh this_script.sh from give_me_error other_script.sh this_script.sh

`ERROR at line 1: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

At the moment, the best idea that I have is using `grep` on variable `res` (see code above). Thanks in advance!

P.S. Custom error codes aren't really an option in this case

> Bash - 4.1.2 Oracle 11.2.0.4.0 EE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn off [globbing](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm):

```
#!/bin/bash

. /path/to/configfile/config.conf

# turn of globbing to prevent directory content expansion
set -o noglob

res=`sqlplus -S $my_user << !
    set head off;
    set feedback off;

    select * from give_me_error;

!`

echo $res
# or
printf "$res\n"
```

The output from your command will then have the actual `*` character, not the expanded list of files that globbing generates.